# Не передаётся изменение состояние чекбокса

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Нужно закинуть изменения чекбокса в локалсторедж. Данные не поступают. Через консоль видно что клики не меняю булевое значение чекбокса. Все время при клики изначально заданное состояние. И тем самым изменения не происходят, а значит и нечего отправлять. Помогите, что проверить?

```js
let addMessage = document.querySelector(".message"),
    addButton = document.querySelector(".add"),
    todo = document.querySelector(".todo");

let todoList = [];

addButton.addEventListener("click", function(){

    let newTodo = {
        todo: addMessage.value,
        checked: false,
        important: false
    };

    todoList.push(newTodo);
    displayMessages();
});

function displayMessages(){
    let displayMessage = "";
    todoList.forEach(function(item, i){
        displayMessage +=
            `<li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="item_${i}">
                <label for="item_${i}" > ${item.todo} </label>
            </li>`;
        todo.innerHTML = displayMessage;
    });
}

todo.addEventListener("change", function(event){ 
    let idInput = event.target.getAttribute("id");
    let forLabel = todo.querySelector("[for=" + idInput + "]");
    let valueLabel = forLabel.innerHTML;

    todoList.forEach(function(item){
        if(item.todo === valueLabel){
            item.checked = !item.checked;
            localStorage.setItem("todoLocal", JSON.stringify(todoList));
        }

        console.log(item.checked) // **тут при каждом клике false**

    });

});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="message" placeholder="Описание">
<button class="add">Добавить</button>
<ul class="todo"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас проверка текста из лейбла не верная `item.todo === valueLabel`. Нужно либо `.trim()`-ить текст перед проверкой, либо удалить пробелы вокруг текста:

```
<label for="item_${i}" >${item.todo}</label>
```

Такие ошибки легко видеть в отладчике или просто через `console.log` каждой строчки.

Comment: Дружище спасибо большое. Может уже поздно было и я устал, но я 2 часа пытался найти ошибку.
"Такие ошибки легко видеть в отладчике" Это через debugger? Как увидеть эти пробелы там?

Comment: @RustamBagirov можно сделать остановку на строчке сравнения и подводить курсор к переменным чтобы видеть их значения. или если точка остановке внутри ифа, то она просто не будет срабатывать из-за невыполнения условия.

Comment: Спасибо. Обычно так и делаю. Но в этой ситуации стормозил. А через консоль как это можно было обнаружить?

Comment: @RustamBagirov ну написать `console.log( item.todo === valueLabel )` выше сравнения. Каждую строчку проверяем, или в каком-то подозрительном районе.

Comment: Ясно! Попробую, спасибо большое еще раз.